# How to create a macro in Google Docs

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs

I am tired of using **Microsft Word**.

I really like **Google Docs**.  But I need to automate some things.

**What do I want**

I want to create a simple shortcut that automates some styles.

1. on a document I will type a text.
2. I select the Text
3. I press a **custom shortcut**
4. The text is set to blue and bold.

**Why am I asking**

There is a lot of good tutorials and documentation for automating Google Spreadsheet.  I tried to find *how to record a macro on Google Docs*, and many variations.  I just can not find a way to do it.

I have searched Stack Overflow, and again I cannot find.

This kind of automation, I think it is easy, but will save a lot of my time when keeping notes.

Comment: By "shortcut", are you referring to **keyboard shortcuts**? Have you already read https://developers.google.com/docs and https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/docs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function setStyleBoldAndBlue() {
  const doc=DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var BoldBlue={};
  BoldBlue[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD]=true;
  BoldBlue[DocumentApp.Attribute.FOREGROUND_COLOR]='#3c69f2';
  let selection=doc.getSelection();
  if(selection) {
    var selectedElements = selection.getRangeElements();
    for(var i=0;i<selectedElements.length;i++) {
      var selElem = selectedElements[i];
      var el = selElem.getElement();
      var isPartial = selElem.isPartial();
      if(isPartial) {
        var selStart = selElem.getStartOffset();
        var selEnd = selElem.getEndOffsetInclusive();
        el.asText().setAttributes(selStart, selEnd, BoldBlue);
      }else {
        var selStart = selElem.getStartOffset();
        var selEnd = selElem.getEndOffsetInclusive();
        el.asParagraph().setAttributes(BoldBlue)
      }
    }
  }
}

function menu() {
  DocumentApp.getUi().createMenu('MyMenu')
  .addItem('Bold and Blue', 'setStyleBoldAndBlue')
  .addToUi();  
}

function onOpen() {
  menu();
}
```

You can access through the MyMenu or attach it to a button. It's not a macro.  It's a script.

Comment: Cooper...And hoe can I set the Macro for a specific Shortcut?

Comment: Cooper, please, add a small diclaimer that this is not a "macro" per se, but has the same capabilities, so as those who stumble upon the question won't think this it is possible to record one (hence the OPs comment...)